# Вопрос по обработчику формы PHP

Tags: php, форма

Добрый вечер,
У обработчика 2 формы,
обработчик отправляет 2 сообщения на email.
Но эти 2 сообщения нужны только при отправке из одной формы в которой заполнен телефон.
соответственно отправка 2 сообщений выполняется следующим образом:

```
$sendsms = mail ($tosms, $subjectsms, $messagesms, $headerssms);
$send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

В массиве `$messagesms` есть `$uphone`
Как при отсутствии информации в `$uphone` убрать или запретить выполнение `$sendsms` ?

Comment: Поставьте проверку `if (isset($messagesms[...]))  $sendsms = ...`

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Конструкция типа  `if (isset($message['uphone'])) {
  $sendsms = NULL;
 } ` не помогает определить значение `$uphone` из `$message = "$uname $uemail $uphone";`

Comment: Вы не спрашивали как определить значение. Вы спрашивали как запретить отправку при отсутствии значения в массиве

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov суть в том что $uphone в $message присутствует всегда, только оно либо со значением либо без, то есть мне нужно найти в массиве значение путем isset далее если значение отличается он NULL или ' ' выполнить функцию, так?

Comment: Руками если удалить $uphone из массива все равно не работает, в $sendsms не подставляется значение null

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Сделал так `if (empty($uphone)) {
 echo ''; }
     else { $sendsms = mail ($tosms, $subjectsms, $messagesms, $headerssms);
 }` Может есть более "прямая конструкция", а то эта на костыль похожа в виде echo

Comment: Хм. Вы пишите что $uphone в массиве $messagesms, а проверяете переменную $uphone. Ну да ладно.
Вы проверяете на пустое значение, а надо на НЕ пустое. 
if (!empty($uphone)) { sendsms(); }